# Can't create an instance of the COM component - Windows Image Acquistion

Tags: c#, windows, sharepoint, iis, com

I have created a com to interact with the scanner using WIA. the com works well, however when i try to use the dll in a Sharepoint project and call the scan method i get the following error:

> Error Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070005.

This could also be a permission problem on IIS.

Has anyone come across this error and found a way to fix it?

Comment: For what it's worth, 0x80070005 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` wrapped into `HRESULT`.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I Tried granting permissions to the Network Service..still no luck.